# Is there an IOS framework for calculations with SI units

Tags: ios

I am taking masses (as g, mg, µg, ng & kg) and volumes (as ml, µl & l) as input to a chemistry app.

Currently I convert all masses to grams and volumes to litres, save in core data and perform any calculations as doubles.

Finally results are then converted back into a meaningful unit
ie 0.000034litres is more useful expressed as 34µl for my customers

What is best practice for working between different units?

Comment: There are no best practices for this. The logic is specific to your app. Do what you need to do to make it work. What information are you actually looking for?

Comment: I was hoping to find a framework using engineering notation (where the exponent is always a multiple of 3) as distinct from scientific notation.  The engineering notation dovetails well for all the SI prefixes like milli, micro, nano etc.  Perhaps I could create an extension on NSDecimalNumber?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few libraries out there but what you are doing is specific so I doubt there is a specific "best practice".

You may want to investigate the properties of `NSDouble`, `CGFloat` however since they might be more suited across devices and give you more options them the primitive double.

There are no unit data types or many built in native converter functions. A number is a number its up to the programmer to give that number meaning in the app's context.

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable engineering formatter at https://github.com/dhoerl/EngineeringNotationFormatter

In addition I created a simple version:

```
-(NSString *)engineeringFormat:(double)value digits:(int)digits {

//calculate exponent in step of 3
int perMill = trunc(log10(value)/3);
if (value<1) {
    perMill -= 1;
}
//calculate mantissa format range of 1 to 1000
double corrected = value;

while (corrected<1) {
    corrected = corrected*1000;
        }
while (corrected>=1000) {
    corrected=corrected/1000;
}
//format number of significant digits
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatDigits = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatDigits.usesSignificantDigits = YES;
numberFormatDigits.maximumSignificantDigits = digits;
NSString *mantissa = [numberFormatDigits stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:corrected]];

//select engineering notation prefix
NSArray *engSuffix = @[@"T",@"G",@"M",@"k",@"",@"m",@"µ",@"n",@"p"];
int index = 4 - perMill;

NSString *result;
if ((index > engSuffix.count-1) || (index<0)) {
    result = @"Out of range";
} else {
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",mantissa,[engSuffix objectAtIndex:index]];
}
return result;
```

}